# How can hide the <asp:BoundField> to don't display, but use its value?

Tags: html, vb.net

I've tried `visible=false` of its property and also tried `e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False`.

But both options are not allowing to access me its value in VB.NET's code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the .Text property to get the value of the cell.

Comment: Yes. I want to use DataField's value and regarding to that will fetch other data.

Comment: @PratikSoni .Text is how you get the value of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I used the HiddenField instead of  so it worked for me.

Thanks all for your help.